# Dark greenish screen on Windows 7 desktop

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, colors

Suddenly, my Windows 7 desktop screen went dark green, making it almost impossible to use the computer. I noticed the problem starts right at boot, because the BIOS also has a very dark color.

I've tried reinstalling the video adapter driver and also reverting it. The adapter is an integrated Intel HD Graphics.

I've tried different monitors and VGA cables, but the problem persists. I've tried setting the color configuration for the adapter to default, but nothing changed.

I've also tried booting into Safe Mode, but as I've said before, the problem starts at boot time, so it didn't solve the problem either.
The drivers and Windows are up-to-date.

How should I proceed? I suspect it's a hardware problem.

Comment: You need a new graphics card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tried different cables and monitors, I'd also suspect the graphics adapter is broken.

In general, if you suspect a hardware problem, then replace the suspect with known-good hardware to test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed an offboard video card and the problem was solved. Unfortunately, another issue ocurred right after this one and now it's the [audio adapter that's not working](http://superuser.com/questions/832387/this-device-could-not-start-code-10-audio-device-not-working-on-windows-7).